# invalid syntax if statement

Tags: python

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Not enough arguments')
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print('Too many arguments')
radius = float(sys.argv[1])
height = float(sys.argv[2])
PI = 3.141592
v = PI*radius*radius*height
else:
    if radius < 0 :
        print('Radius cannot be negative')
    elif radius > 0 and height < 0 :
        print('Height cannot be negative')
    else:
        print(int(v))
```

I keep getting syntax error with "else:". Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The only syntax error in this code is the missing `if`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey is correct if there is no more code. If there is, it would help to see it.

Comment: This is only the last part of my code. The rest of it are correct so I didn't put them on.

Comment: Please include all relevant code and the complete error message.

Comment: So, indeed your code before the `else` is misindented. And by the way, your code fails when the `radius` is zero and `height` is negative.

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code. could you help with that? Thanks.

Comment: I can only repeat my earlier comment: There's a missing `if`.

Comment: Where should I add the missing if? I'm a total beginner so could you please be more specific?

Comment: On line 10, you got `else:`, where is it's `if`? Because if you're familiar with `if-else` then there can be no `else` without an `if`!

Comment: You must move `radius = float(sys.argv[1]); height = float(sys.argv[2]); PI = 3.141592; v = PI*radius*radius*height` after the `else` statement and indent it. Also, there is `math.pi` that should be used instead of any other `pi`.

Comment: In line 2? Is it because I put the variables in between the statement?

Comment: This completely depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Right now, it looks like you don't need that `else:` and everything after it should be un-indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

Try with this code:-

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Not enough arguments')
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print('Too many arguments')
else:
    radius = float(sys.argv[1])
    height = float(sys.argv[2])
    if radius < 0 :
        print('Radius cannot be negative')
    elif radius > 0 and height < 0 :
        print('Height cannot be negative')
    else:
        PI = 3.141592
        v = PI*radius*radius*height
        print(int(v))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ python3 test200.py 25 10
19634

$ python3 test200.py 2 10
125

$ python3 test200.py 2 -10
Height cannot be negative

$ python3 test200.py -2 10
Radius cannot be negative
```

Comment: Okay. Now I see the problem. THank you!

Comment: @Jesse Happy to help! Please accept the answer, if it solved the problem.

Comment: Your code has a major flaw: It attempts to solve the problem even when the program is invoked incorrectly (e.g., when there are not enough arguments).  The original OP's code is actuially better than yours.

Answer (score 2):

There is `indentation` problem with your code. Also I change your logic a bit as below. You only want to calculate `v` when all condition is fulfilled:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Not enough arguments')
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print('Too many arguments')
else:
    radius = float(sys.argv[1])
    height = float(sys.argv[2])    

    if radius < 0 :
        print('Radius cannot be negative')
    elif radius > 0 and height < 0 :
        print('Height cannot be negative')
    else:
        PI = 3.141592
        v = PI*radius*radius*height
        print(int(v))
```

Good luck!

Comment: It'll never give the result even on the right arguments!

Comment: What is the difference between this code and mine? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jesse , I edited my answer. You have an outer `else` case, which it indicate `len(sys.argv) = 3`, if I am not wrong. This `else` condition need to be met first. Then you get `radius` & `height` from `sys.argv[1] & [2]`. Then if `radius` & `height` both matches your conditions, only proceed to calculate `v` for it. So I just rearrange the lines of code to reflect this logic.